# Tymon JWTAUTH exclude routes from token

Tags: laravel-5

I installed laravel 5.6 and configured tymon jwtauth token.

All working fine and done.

In laravel 5.1 i used this function to exclude function from jwt authentication:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->middleware('jwt.auth', ['except' => ['login']]);
}
```

tried also :

```
public function __construct() {

    $this->middleware('jwt.auth')->except([
        'login'
    ]);
}
```

It's not working in laravel 5.6, any idea? I want to exclide the login function so the user can login, take the token and send it with each request.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [

'jwt.auth' => 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\GetUserFromToken',
'jwt.refresh' => 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\RefreshToken',
]
```

I was putting this in

protected $Middleware

in api.php I put my routes not in web.php

```
Route::post('user/register', 'APIRegisterController@register');
Route::post('user/login', 'APILoginController@login');
Route::middleware('jwt.auth')->get('testFunc', 'testController@testFunc');
```